# How pass a parameter for a foreign key in a JPA query when it's an object?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a class called Affecter with some attributes, and some ManyToOne foreign key. I want to create a query which search some data with a parameter for this foreign key. But, this foreign key is represented by an object in my class, so when I make the query, I get the following error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Parameter value did not match excepted type

This is my Entity :

```
package org.safran.cockpit.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
@Table(name = "affecter")
@Data
@Entity
public class Affecter implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "dateEntree", nullable = false)
  private Date dateEntree;

  @Column(name = "dateSortie")
  private Date dateSortie;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idAffaire", nullable = false)
  private Affaire affaire;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idService", nullable = false)
  private Service service;
```

This is my query :

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Affecter a WHERE a.service = ?1 AND 
a.dateSortie=''")
  public List<Affecter> findAffecterByService(Integer service);
```

And this is how I call my query :

```
 @GetMapping(value="/listAffecterService/{idService}")
    public List<Affecter> listAffecterService(@PathVariable(name="idService") int idService){
        return affecterRepository.findAffecterByService(idService);
    }
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a FROM Affecter a WHERE a.service = ?1
```

So you're comparing `a.service` with your parameter. `a.service` is of type Service. So your parameter must be of type Service, too.

Given that you have the ID of the service, either you first get the Service associated with this ID, and pass the service as argument of your query, or you compare IDs in your queries:

```
SELECT a FROM Affecter a WHERE a.service.id = ?1
```